# Display User Info from JWT Token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

I have a large scale application builded on React and Redux. I want to display User Info in the User's Profile. The data are stored in the store.js. I just want to display them. What files should I have to create to achieve this?

Comment: You should provide a bit more information, it is very unclear what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to extract the user claims from the JWT? Where does your user data come from? You just say `store.js` but that doesn't tell us much. Does it go through your reducer? How is this stored data structured? Are you asking for help retrieving the user data or how to create a React component to present it? Show us some code of what you have tried so far, please.

Comment: I want to make a React component for present it in the User Profile page, but I am very new to React and Redux and I don't know what files are required for achieving it

Comment: You really need to share some more information if you want to get help. At the very least answer some of the questions in my first comment. We have no idea what you have right now, so there's no information at all to go on from.

Comment: Tricky to tell you how to do it knowing that you're not at all familiar with react, my advice would be to watch this channel it will be a huge help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiLVAXlVYR0&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBbSLZjvleMwldX8jGgXV6a